# How to have an indefinite depth level of loops inside a class

Tags: python

I have a python class for multilinear regression, in which I have a list of factors `self.facts` and a list of polynomial coefficients `self.params`. Let us call the order of the polynomial `self.order`. I am trying to write a method which prints the formula with an output like :

```
self.params[0] + self.params[1]*self.facts[0] + ... + self.params[...]*self.facts[0]*self.facts[1]+...
```

Example for

```
self.order = 3
self.facts = ['f1','f2']
self.params = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I would like to have as an output :

```
(0) + (1)xf1 + (2)xf2 + (3)xf1^2 + (4)xf1xf2 + (5)xf2^2 + (6)xf1^3 + (7)xf1^2xf2 + (8)xf1xf2^2 + (9)xf2^3
```

I implemented the method up to the order 3 and it works fine:

```
def formula(self):
    if self.order>3:
        print('Not yet implemented for order >3 !...')
        return

    s=self.col+' = '
    if self.presence[0]:
        s+='('+str(self.params[0])+')'
    for i in [i for i in range(len(self.facts)) if self.presence[i+1]]:
        s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[i+1])+')x'+self.facts[i]

    if self.order>1:
        ind = len(self.facts)+1
        for i in range(len(self.facts)):
            for j in range(i,len(self.facts)):
                if self.presence[ind]:
                    s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
                    if i==j:
                        s+=self.facts[i]+'^2'
                    else:
                        s+=self.facts[i]+'x'+self.facts[j]
                ind+=1
                
    if self.order>2:
        for i in range(len(self.facts)):
            for j in range(i,len(self.facts)):
                for k in range(j,len(self.facts)):
                    if self.presence[ind]:
                        s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
                        s+=((self.facts[i]+'^3') if i==j and j==k else ((self.facts[i]+'^2'+'x'+self.facts[k]) if i==j else ((self.facts[i]+'x'+self.facts[j]+'^2') if j==k else (self.facts[i]+'x'+self.facts[j]+'x'+self.facts[k]))))
                    ind+=1

    return s
```

(`self.presence` indicates weather the term has been kept or not in the regression).

Now I would like to implement this for any value of `self.order`. I cannot find a proper way to do this since I cannot add an infinite number of loops. The only solution I came with is by creating the desired number of loops inside a string, and then using `exec()` :

```
def formula2(self):

    order=self.order
    se=''
    se+='s=self.col+\' = \''+'\n'
    se+='ind=0\n'
    se+='if self.presence[0]:'+'\n\t'
    se+='s+=\'(\'+str(self.params[0])+\')\''+'\n'
    se+='ind+=1\n'
    for o in range(1,order+1):
        for io in range(o):
            se+='for i'+str(io)+' in range('+(('i'+str(io-1)+',') if io>0 else '')+'len(self.facts)):\n'+''.join(['\t']*(io+1))
        se+='if self.presence[ind]:\n'+''.join(['\t']*(o+1))
        se+='s+=(\' + \' if s!=\'\' else \'\')+\'(\'+str(self.params[ind])+\')x\''+'\n'+''.join(['\t']*(o+1))
        se+='l=[self.facts[eval(\'i\'+str(io))] for io in range('+str(o)+')]'+'\n'+''.join(['\t']*(o+1))
        se+='s+=\'x\'.join([ll+((\'^\'+str(l.count(ll))) if l.count(ll)>1 else \'\') for ll in np.unique(l)])'+'\n'+''.join(['\t']*(o+1))
        se+='ind+=1'+'\n'

    exec(se)
    return s
```

The function creates a string `se` that creates the desired output string `s`, and then executing string `se` would set me the output string `s` that I want to return. For example for `self.order=3`, the output of `print(se)` is:

```
s=self.col+' = '
ind=0
if self.presence[0]:
    s+='('+str(self.params[0])+')'
ind+=1
for i0 in range(len(self.facts)):
    if self.presence[ind]:
        s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
        l=[self.facts[eval('i'+str(io))] for io in range(1)]
        s+='x'.join([ll+(('^'+str(l.count(ll))) if l.count(ll)>1 else '') for ll in np.unique(l)])
        ind+=1
for i0 in range(len(self.facts)):
    for i1 in range(i0,len(self.facts)):
        if self.presence[ind]:
            s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
            l=[self.facts[eval('i'+str(io))] for io in range(2)]
            s+='x'.join([ll+(('^'+str(l.count(ll))) if l.count(ll)>1 else '') for ll in np.unique(l)])
            ind+=1
for i0 in range(len(self.facts)):
    for i1 in range(i0,len(self.facts)):
        for i2 in range(i1,len(self.facts)):
            if self.presence[ind]:
                s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
                l=[self.facts[eval('i'+str(io))] for io in range(3)]
                s+='x'.join([ll+(('^'+str(l.count(ll))) if l.count(ll)>1 else '') for ll in np.unique(l)])
                ind+=1
```

which is exactly what I want to execute. The problem is that I cannot make it be set in this class environment and I am afraid it is not possible at all. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to make the `exec()` work inside the class so that I can return string `s`?
2. Is there a cleverer way of defining an infinite level of loops?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You might want to read up on **recursion**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If useful to anyone, I finally found the solution, with the 'repeat' option of itertools.product!

Here is the solution that works:

```
def formula3(self):

    s=self.col+' = '
    ind=0
    if self.presence[0]:
        s+='('+str(self.params[0])+')'
    ind+=1

    # Nested loops !!
    for k in range(1,self.order+1):
        for t in itertools.product(list(range(len(self.facts))),repeat=k):
            l=len(t)
            cond=True
            for it in range(1,l) if l>1 else []:
                cond&=t[it]>=t[it-1]
            if cond:
                t=list(t)
                if self.presence[ind]:
                    s+=(' + ' if s!='' else '')+'('+str(self.params[ind])+')x'
                    l=[self.facts[tt] for tt in t]
                    s+='x'.join([ll+(('^'+str(l.count(ll))) if l.count(ll)>1 else '') for ll in np.unique(l)])
                ind+=1
    return s
```

The two for loops produce t which is any (1-to-n) combination of factors (n being the order). If you want to have starting condition (for example start at index of (i-1_-th loop) you must explicit them with a condition. So with my condition cond, t is (0,) (1,) (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,1) (1,1,1) which is equivalent to the different loop levels I had.